# Mac mini with 2 MacOS installs backup both MacOS installs

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I have a Mac mini with a external SSD. On internal SSD of my Mac mini I have a MacOS install for private use. On the external SSD I also have MacOS installed but this one I use for my work. So if I want to change between work and the private one I need to reboot. This works all fine.

But the issue is with the Time Machine backups. I can backup one of the MacOS installs. But when I want to backup the second MacOS install I get the following error.

> ‘The disk “timemachine” already contains an encrypted backup for this computer. Would you like to continue using the existing encrypted backup, erase the existing backup and start a new encrypted backup with a different password, or choose a different disk?’

[image: The disk “timemachine” already contains an encrypted backup for this computer. Would you like to continue using the existing encrypted backup, erase the existing backup and start a new encrypted backup with a different password, or choose a different disk?]

With the options:

- Choose A Different Disk
- Erase Existing Backup
- Use Existing Backup

For Time Machine I use a Synology NAS. So how can I backup both MacOS installs separately?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way around this issue. My Synology NAS gives an option to setup multiple Time Machine directories. So I have now 2 Time Machine directories on my Synology NAS and backup each of my MacOS install to it's own Time Machine directory.